Why is my code giving a memory error when it was working previously?
I have this python script where I have RNA seq data with 54,000 genes and have to do a pairwise correlation with each pair of genes:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities
%matplotlib tk
Data = RNA seq data
Data = pd.read_csv(Data)
Correlation = Data.corr(method = 'pearson', numeric_only = "False")
print(Correlation)
Filtered = Correlation[(Correlation.abs() >= 0.8)]
Filtered = Filtered.replace(1.0, np.nan)

The code has worked in the past, but when I run it now I get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 1
----> 1 Filtered = Filtered.replace(1.0, np.nan)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:7909, in NDFrame.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   7903         new_data = self._mgr.replace_regex(
   7904             to_replace=to_replace,
   7905             value=value,
   7906             inplace=inplace,
   7907         )
   7908     else:
-> 7909         new_data = self._mgr.replace(
   7910             to_replace=to_replace, value=value, inplace=inplace
   7911         )
   7912 else:
   7913     raise TypeError(
   7914         f'Invalid "to_replace" type: {repr(type(to_replace).__name__)}'
   7915     )

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\base.py:228, in DataManager.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace)
    226 assert not lib.is_list_like(to_replace)
    227 assert not lib.is_list_like(value)
--> 228 return self.apply_with_block(
    229     "replace",
    230     to_replace=to_replace,
    231     value=value,
    232     inplace=inplace,
    233     using_cow=using_copy_on_write(),
    234 )

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:354, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    352         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    353     else:
--> 354         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    355     result_blocks = extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    357 out = type(self).from_blocks(result_blocks, self.axes)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:728, in Block.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, mask, using_cow)
    723         return [self] if inplace else [self.copy()]
    725 elif self._can_hold_element(value):
    726     # TODO(CoW): Maybe split here as well into columns where mask has True
    727     # and rest?
--> 728     blk = self._maybe_copy(using_cow, inplace)
    729     putmask_inplace(blk.values, mask, value)
    730     if not (self.is_object and value is None):
    731         # if the user *explicitly* gave None, we keep None, otherwise
    732         #  may downcast to NaN

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:660, in Block._maybe_copy(self, using_cow, inplace)
    658     blk = self.copy(deep=deep)
    659 else:
--> 660     blk = self if inplace else self.copy()
    661 return blk

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:645, in Block.copy(self, deep)
    643 refs: BlockValuesRefs | None
    644 if deep:
--> 645     values = values.copy()
    646     refs = None
    647 else:

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 22.3 GiB for an array with shape (54735, 54735) and data type float64

Why? I have 95 GB of available RAM, so I think the allocation should be possible.

Here is something that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932913/memoryerror-unable-to-allocate-30-4-gib-for-an-array-with-shape-725000-277-7

I have 95 GB of available RAM Perhaps that full amount is not available to your program, or perhaps it is not available in a contiguous region.

does it work with a smaller sized dataset ?, what's the maximum dataset size you can get it working with !, anything changed on your system ?
